# We couldn't save your logging selections. Please try again

Tags: error, salesforce-for-outlook, plugin-bug

When a users logs an email from outlook to salesforce, using the Salesforce plugin, the user gets this error

[image]

Tried the following resolutions without success

1. Removed the saved password in Chrome > Settings > Privacy and Security  > Password
2. Cleared browsing history and cached data Chrome > Settings
3. uninstalled and reinstalled the salesforce plugin
   restarted the computer

Can someone suggest how to resolve this error, or what could be the cause of this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are also experiencing this problem in our org when logging while replying in the Outlook desktop client (logging from a folder - Inbox, Sent, etc. - works as expected).  The error occurs when the user selects Save to save the logging selection.  However, the bcc field is completed successfully and when the user clicks Send the email is logged to our org.  So it is not clear what the real problem is that is generating this pop up message.

We have found that the outlook.com version works correctly when logging while replying.  That is, there is no error message to distract the user.

Salesforce users are reporting a similar problem that started recently, too.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000009M90CAE?tab=discussion

Comment: Thanks @ChetSeidel for the response. We reached out to Salesforce Support, and were informed the following 'The issue happening in Outlook is what we've seen recently after the Winter'22 release and it's becoming a trending in lots of the cases we received. '

Comment: @GroundToCloud It took a while a Known Issue has shown up, too.  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000020aqTQAQ